# Draw image with only grayscale value array in java

Tags: java, rgb, pixel, javax.imageio

I am starting to learn image processing in Java, here is my question: I have an array of values (I assume pixel values) for a graycale image, one for each (x,y) position. The image is 96x96.
An example of these values is:

```
238 
236 
237
238
240
240 
239 
241
241
243
240
239 
231 
212
190
173 
148
122
104
```

My question is, how can I draw this image by just using these pixel values? The reason I ask this, is because usually I have the original image available, and I extract the red, green and blue component values for each pixel. But in this case, if I want to do something like this:

```
// after for loop in which I do  
//Color newColor = new Color(red,green,blue);
//image.setRGB(x,y,newColor.getRGB());

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JLabel lblimage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
mainPanel.add(lblimage);

// add more components here
frame.add(mainPanel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I can't create a Color class because I don't have the components for the red, blue and green values of each pixel.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I'm mistaking concepts, if so I apologize.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Indented code blocks require a preceding newline in markdown, just as an FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Greyscale means that all three color components - R, G, and B - are the same. So, use the greyscale values as the color components:

```
Color newColor = new Color(pixelValue[x][y], pixelValue[x][y], pixelValue[x][y]);
image.setRGB(x, y, newColor.getRGB());
```

Comment: Ah, so that's the reason why there is only one value for each pixel, thank you! I will try it out

Comment: @manuelmourato There are a few ways to convert pixels to grayscale. [Here's some of them](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/)